# AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute

Tags: python, nonetype

I, as a python novice, get the following error message when executing a code which I have received by the author:

```
line 412, in add_family
    mother_birth_ref = mother.get_birth_ref()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_birth_ref'
```

The relevant part of the code must be this one here:

```
def write_child_stats(self):
    file = open("%s/intern/child-stats.txt" % self.dir_name, 'w')

def add_family(family, marriage_event, divorce_event):
    father_handle = family.get_father_handle()
    mother_handle = family.get_mother_handle()

    father = self.database.get_person_from_handle(father_handle)
    father_birth_ref = father.get_birth_ref()
    father_birth = None
    if father_birth_ref:
        father_birth = self.database.get_event_from_handle(father_birth_ref.ref)

    mother = self.database.get_person_from_handle(mother_handle)
    mother_birth_ref = mother.get_birth_ref()
    mother_birth = None
    if mother_birth_ref:
        mother_birth = self.database.get_event_from_handle(mother_birth_ref.ref)

    children = []
    child_refs = family.get_child_ref_list()
    for child_handle in child_refs:
        child = self.database.get_person_from_handle(child_handle.ref)
        if child:
            child_birth_ref = child.get_birth_ref()
            if child_birth_ref:
                child_birth = self.database.get_event_from_handle(child_birth_ref.ref)
                children.append("%04d-%02d-%02d" % child_birth.get_date_object().get_ymd())
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: `get_person_from_handle` is returning `None` for `mother_handle`. Post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mother = self.database.get_person_from_handle(mother_handle)
```

This line is returning `None`. Check `get_person_from_handle` function.

Alternatively, you can add a check :

```
mother = self.database.get_person_from_handle(mother_handle)
mother_birth_ref = None
mother_birth = None
if mother:
    mother_birth_ref = mother.get_birth_ref()
if mother_birth_ref:
    mother_birth = self.database.get_event_from_handle(mother_birth_ref.ref)
```